# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'author' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am scraping a website's detail pages from a listing page, with some differences in each detail page.

1st detail page:

```
<div class="td-post-content">
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
        <strong>[ Karda Natam ]</strong>
        <br>
        <strong>ITANAGAR, May 6:</strong> Nacho, Taksing, Siyum and ...
        <br> “Offices are without ...
    </p>
</div>
```

2nd detail page:

```
<div class="td-post-content">
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
        <strong>Guwahati, May 6 (PTI)</strong> Sarbananda Sonowal today ...
        <br> “Books are a potent tool to create ...
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to parse the author and post date from the detail page:

```
class ArunachaltimesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css("...").extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        strong_elements = response.css("div.td-ss-main-content").css("div.td-post-content").css("p > strong::text").extract()
        for strong in strong_elements:
            if ', ' in strong:
                news_date = strong.split(', ')[1].replace(":", "")
            elif '[ ' and ' ]' in strong:
                author = strong
            else:
                news_date = None
                author = None
        yield {
            'author': author,
            'news_date': news_date
        }
```

But I am getting this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'author' referenced before assignment

What am I doing wrong here? Could you please how to get the author and news date from each page respectively. Thank you.

Comment: No value is assigned to `author` if the loop body is not executed, or if only the first `if` branch is taken.

Comment: @jiakai Yes, solved the problem by providing a default `None` value to both author and news date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem, by providing a default value `None` to both `author` and `news_date`:

```
def parse_detail(self, response):
    strong_elements = response.css("div.td-ss-main-content").css("div.td-post-content").css("p > strong::text").extract()
    author = None
    news_date = None
    for strong in strong_elements:
        if ', ' in strong:
            news_date = strong.split(", ")[1].replace(":", "").split(" (")[0]
        elif '[ ' and ' ]' in strong:
            author = strong.strip("[ ").strip(" ]")
        else:
            news_date = None
            author = None
    yield {
        'author': author,
        'news_date': news_date
    }
```